# Runtime Efficiency of ApplicationRecord's find() method O(1)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

Creating a Model file in a Rails application, the resulting class implements the ApplicationRecord interface. I cannot find any documentation for ApplicationRecord; the only thing that comes up is ActiveRecord, which I assume is an earlier, deprecated version. Looking through the documentation, it is not clear to me what kind of data structure this is. Am I correct in assuming that calling find() on this always takes constant time without regard to the amount of data?

Comment: `find()` loads a single record by the defined primary key from the DB and raises an exception when not found. The performance of finding the record mostly depends on how your DB handles that query and if there is an appropriate index on that table. And the size of the returned data, because Ruby on Rails will read and initialize an instance of `ActiveRecord::Base` from that data.
Why do you ask? Do you have an issue with `find`'s performance? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: _"I cannot find any documentation for ApplicationRecord"_ – see [Creating Active Record Models](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#creating-active-record-models)

Comment: You will have a file called `application_record.rb` in the application. You will see this is simply a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base`. `ActiveRecord` is highly compositional so depending on what you are looking for it may be located in any number of included modules. [API Documents](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ApplicationRecord` is just a local base class generated in Rails apps to allow adding things for all models without monkey-patching the Rails class. Look in `app/models/application_record.rb`.

So yeah, the docs for models is in [the `ActiveRecord` docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord.html). Also [the various model guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/) are another great resource.

> Am I correct in assuming that calling find() on this always takes constant time without regard to the amount of data?

Depends on your DB/schema/indexes/etc.